# Who is this superhero?

Tags: comics, character-identification

Who is this character? I cannot figure it out.

[image: comic book characters sitting at a table]

Comment: Captain Catsup?  :P

Comment: +1 Because it took me back to my old Spawn days when I first discovered him as well. BTW, your battery is running low as well...

Comment: [Original image](http://www.timeart.co.uk/superheroes-last-supper,p/) if anyone is interested. Also, I think the Hulk is gonna have words with Spawn over his mishandling of condiments. ;)

Comment: @gnovice Did he just spray Hulk with the ketchup?

Comment: Sadly, Heather can not accept the correct answer because his/her battery died.

Comment: This looks like it may be Spawn's "last supper."

Answer (score 35):

That would be [Spawn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spawn_%28comics%29), created by [Todd McFarlane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Todd_McFarlane) and published by [Image Comics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_Comics).

[image]

Answer (score 10):

This question already has a correct answer, but I'll take it one step further and identify every superhero in the original artwork... because I can, and it's fun.

[image]

From left to right:

1. [Captain America](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_America) (Marvel Comics)
2. [The Flash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_(comics)) (DC Comics)
3. [**Spawn**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spawn_(comics)) (Image Comics)
4. [The Hulk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hulk_(comics)) (Marvel Comics)
5. [Batman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman) (DC Comics)
6. [Wonder Woman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wonder_Woman) (DC Comics)
7. [Superman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman) (DC Comics)
8. [Thor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thor_(Marvel_Comics)) (Marvel Comics)
9. [Wolverine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolverine_(character)) (Marvel Comics)
10. [Green Lantern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Lantern) (DC Comics)
11. [Spider-Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man) (Marvel Comics)
12. [Venom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venom_(comics)) (Marvel Comics)
13. [Iron Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Man) (Marvel Comics)

***Original Artwork:*** "Last Supper" by Michael Kozlov.
http://www.timeart.co.uk/last-supper,p/